# How to ignore a failing request in a VS load test

Tags: visual-studio-2012, load-testing

I'm creating a load test in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate for a web page. The page has some javascript that requests a resource from a remote server. That request often fails and the iteration of the load test fails. As the resource is not at all important, I'd like the test to succeed if that's the only problem. Can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In the Request properties, set `Ignore HTTP Status Code` to `True`.